# Nginx proxy_redirect does not rewrite location header in response

Tags: nginx, proxy

I have a simple problem

- setup a load balancer using Nginx for 6 upstream servers

I have done this

```
upstream hisservers {  
         ip_hash;  
         server A;  
         server B;  
         server C;  
         server D;  
         server E;  
         server F; }  
 
 server {  
         listen 80;  
         server_name test.server;  
         location / {  
                 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host:$server_port;  
                 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;  
                 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;  
                 proxy_pass http://hisservers;  
         } }
```

but the problem is... above solution does not rewrite the location header in response.. so I always get redirected to any of those 6 upstreams

then I did this

`proxy_redirect http://hisservers /;`

still, it doesn't work
finally, I did this

`proxy_redirect http://A/ /;`
`proxy_redirect http://B/ /;`
`proxy_redirect http://C/ /;`
`proxy_redirect http://D/ /;`
`proxy_redirect http://E/ /;`
`proxy_redirect http://F/ /;`

and it works.

I thought that Nginx by default will match the upstreams and rewrite the location header.

any tips on this?

I think my solution is quite hacky

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each of your servers return different hostnames in their Location response headers, and so your `proxy_redirect` statement(s) must match these hostnames.

You can match each hostname using separate `proxy_redirect` statements, as you have demonstrated at the end of your question.

Alternatively, `proxy_redirect` allows you to use regular expressions. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_redirect) for details.

For example:

```
proxy_redirect ~*http://[^/]+(/.*)$ $1;
```

The above statement should be a substitute for the six statements at the end of your question. The `[^/]+` expression matches any hostname, and the `(/.*)$` expression captures the URI to be used in the replacement.

Comment: great! thank you for the feedback.. i  though nginx will automatically handle the rewrite header