# GeoServer web UI redirects to vanilla HTTP

Tags: nginx, geoserver

I have the standalone version of GeoServer 2.21.0 running behind an NGINX reverse proxy. Whenever I attempt to do anything with the web UI, Wicket is redirecting me to HTTP when I need it to send me to HTTPS.

The server *does* serve up map tiles correctly. It's just that the web UI is completely dysfunctional as it's running over HTTPS and GeoServer redirects everything to HTTP for some reason.

I also have the CSRF whitelist set but I'm having problems before CSRF comes into play. If I do so much as go to https://myserver/geoserver it redirects me to http://myserver/geoserver/web/?0 which doesn't work.

I have a GeoServer instance running behind NGINX. NGINX is configured like this:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9191/;        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host   $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port   $server_port;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
    proxy_redirect off;
}
```

I have the Proxy Base URL configured to https://myserver/geoserver and Use headers for Proxy URL is enabled.

What might be causing this? A Google search wasn't very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was `proxy_redirect ~*http://[^/]+(/.*)$ $1;`

This rules tells NGINX to remove everything from the beginning **http** all the way up through the hostname in the redirect so that the redirect sends the user to the reverse proxy's (i.e. NGINX) host.

[relevant answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70287119/1119852)